# Springboot等で構築したWebアプリケーションにて、Google Formsで回答した内容の集計や値の取得が可能かを知りたい（APIやライブラリを経由して値を取得可能か）

Tags: google-apps-script, spring-boot, kotlin, google-api, google-drive-sdk

現在、Springboot（Kotlin）を利用して以下のWebアプリケーションを構築を検討しています。

・WebアプリケーションにはGoogleアカウントを利用し、OAuth2認証を介してログインする
・Google Formsの回答フォームは逐次作成される想定のためWebアプリケーションには組み込まず、
　別ウィンドウを開いて回答を行う

その際、以下の情報をGoogle Formsから取得し、集計や連携を行いたいのですが、
Google FormsとGoogleアカウントを連携し、独自のWebアプリケーションにて
値を取得するような事は可能なのかが分からず、困っております。

具体的には以下を実現したいと考えております。
・Google Formsの点数等の情報を取得し、Webアプリケーション上にて集計や編集を行いたい
・編集した内容はGoogle Formsに反映させたい
・ユーザーを個別に判別したいため、Googleアカウントと連携したい

ご教示いただけたら幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Google Formへ値を書き込んでSubmitするとSpreadsheetへまとめられます。これを利用するのはいかがでしょうか。例えばSpreadsheetをWeb publishとして公開することでも値を取得することができます。この場合、read onlyです。「ユーザーを個別に判別したいため、Googleアカウントと連携したい」について、Google Formは全てのユーザからのデータが保存されますので、ユーザ毎にデータを取得したい場合は、Google Formでメールアドレスを取得するようにすると、ユーザ毎にメールアドレスでフィルタをすることでデータを取得できるかと思われます。やりたいことへの私の理解が間違っておりましたら謝罪します。

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。
Google FormのSubmit　→　SpreadSheetが利用できるのですね。
Google Form上で設定したメールアドレスもSpreadSheetで取得し、ユーザー判断ができるか試してみます。
ご認識の内容で合っています。記載いただいて助かりました。ありがとうございます。